# $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^n\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\text{e}^{\frac{x}{2}}\text{d}x$ Evaluating this limit

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, limits

How to evaluate :
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^n\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\text{e}^{\frac{x}{2}}\text{d}x$$

Comment: Do you know the dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: @Arjang, if a title is only latex then you can't open it with right click -> new tab.  Don't take the words out of titles.

Comment: @AntonioVargas : Thank you for letting me know, I try something else and test it too.

Comment: @AntonioVargas : Although ctrl + click would work when there is no test, I'll add some text to avoid that problem, thanks again

Comment: @AntonioVargas : Antonio I am trying to make the titles shorter so the related side links can fit and are their relevance is clearly  visible. Having "Evaluate" vs "How to evaluate" be a help in that regards, but if you know of any problems that would cause before I it instead?

Comment: @Arjang that's a great point.  The best compromise I can think of would be to put some text after the latex, like "$\lim \int n \,dx$ - Evaluating this limit".  I agree that there are other options, like ctrl+click or middle click when using a 3-button mouse, but I think we should be going for maximal usability.

Comment: @AntonioVargas : load and clear, WILCO

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the fact that
$$\left(1 - \dfrac{x}n \right)^n \leq e^{-x}$$
i.e.
$$\left(1 - \dfrac{x}n \right)^n e^{x/2} \leq e^{-x/2}$$
and
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 - \dfrac{x}n \right)^n = e^{-x}$$
Consider the sequence $$f_n(x) = \begin{cases} \left(1 - \dfrac{x}{n} \right)^n e^{x/2} & x \in [0,n]\\ 0 & x > n\end{cases}$$ which is dominated by $g(x) = e^{-x/2}$. Now apply dominated convergence theorem to get that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^n f_n(x) dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^{\infty} f_n(x) dx = \int_0^{\infty} \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) dx = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x/2} dx = 2$$

Comment: I see, I have to look over that theorem now:)

Comment: Is it possible to do it in other ways? ie. squeeze theorem?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a proof using just the squeeze theorem (as requested by Ryan in the comments on Marvis' answer).

For $x = o(n)$ and $n$ large enough we have

$$
n \log\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right) = -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k n^{k-1}} \geq - x - \frac{x^2}{n},
$$

so that

$$
\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n \geq e^{-x-x^2/n}.
$$

This gives

$$
\begin{align*}
\int_0^n \left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n e^{x/2} \,dx &\geq \int_0^{n^{1/4}} \left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n e^{x/2}\,dx \\
&\geq \int_0^{n^{1/4}} e^{-x/2-x^2/n}\,dx \\
&\geq e^{-1/\sqrt{n}} \int_0^{n^{1/4}} e^{-x/2}\,dx.
\end{align*}
$$

The last expression converges to

$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-x/2}\,dx = 2
$$
as $n \to \infty$.  Marvis' answer shows that

$$
\int_0^n \left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n e^{x/2} \,dx \leq \int_0^\infty e^{-x/2}\,dx = 2,
$$

so we conclude from the squeeze theorem that

$$
\int_0^n \left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n e^{x/2}\,dx \longrightarrow 2
$$

as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Many thanks! :)

Comment: @Anonio Vargas, What leads you to a upper limit of $n^{\frac14}$? Just observation? :)

Comment: @Ryan There are three main conditions I needed to satisfy.  I wanted to replace $n$ by something, say $a_n$, so that $$\begin{align}& a_n \to \infty, \\&a_n/n \to 0, \text{ and} \\&a_n^2/n \to 0\end{align}$$ as $n \to \infty$.  The first condition makes sure the upper limit of integration goes to $\infty$.  The second condition makes sure that $x/n \to 0$ for all $x$ in the interval of integration $[0,a_n]$, which is the condition I need to satisfy so that the first inequality in my post is true.  These first two requirements are satisfied by $a_n = \sqrt{n}$, for example.  (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) Now for $0 \leq x \leq a_n$ we have $e^{-x^2/n} \geq e^{-a_n^2/n}$, and I want this to have a limit of $1$ as $n \to \infty$.  This is not true for $a_n = \sqrt{n}$ but it is true for smaller $a_n$, for example $a_n = n^{1/4}$.

Comment: Thx for your explanation:)

Comment: @Ryan, Sure thing!