# Applying Dominated Convergence Theorem to solve $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^n(1-\frac{x}{n})^ne^{-x}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^n(1-\frac{x}{n})^ne^{-x}dx$$

I am going to use the Dominated Convergence Theorem to solve this.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^{\infty}\chi_{[0, n]}(1-\frac{x}{n})^ne^{-x}dx$$

**Step 1 - Find a dominating function $g$**

Let $h_n = (1-\frac{x}{n})^n$

$\chi_{[0, n]}$ is telling us that $h_n = 0$ whenever $x > n$. This means that $h_n(0) = 1$ and $h_n(n) = 0$ for all $n$. So $h_n$ is a sequence of measurable functions that is bounded above by $1$.

Let $f_n = (1-\frac{x}{n})^n \cdot e^{-x} = h_n \cdot e^{-x}$. This also has a maximum value of $1$. So $f_n$ is dominated by the constant function $g(x) = 1$.

**Step 2 - Find a function $f$ such that $f_n \to f$ pointwise almost everywhere**

Now consider $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1-\frac{x}{n})^ne^{-x}$

$e^{-x}\cdot e^{-x} = e^{-2x}$

So we have that $f_n \to f = e^{-2x}$ $f$ is integrable and it's integral is 
\begin{align*}
&= \lim_{k \to \infty}\int_0^{k}e^{-2x}dx\\
&= \lim_{k \to \infty}-\frac{1}{2}e^{-2x}\mid_0^k\\
&= \lim_{k \to \infty}[-\frac{1}{2}e^{-2\cdot k} - (-\frac{1}{2} e^{2\cdot0})]\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}(0) + \frac{1}{2}\\
&= \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

So we have a sequence of functions $f_n$ such that $\mid f_n \mid \le g$ and $f_n \to f$, with $f$ integrable. Hence, by the Dominated Convergence Theorem we have that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^{\infty} f_n = \int_0^{\infty} f = \frac{1}{2}$$

Have I made any incorrect assumptions in this solution?

Comment: I have just noticed that $\int_0^{\infty} g(x) dx = \int_0^{\infty} 1 dx = \infty.$ Hence this $g$ is not integrable and the theorem can't be applied with this $g$!

Comment: Check [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/305932/5531) out.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Cheers, that's very similar. I just choose $g = e^{-x}$ for my case.

Comment: I should mention that the inequality $(1-x/n)^n < e^{-x}$ can be proved using Bernoulli's inequality.  I went through the steps in the beginning of [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/522245/5531).